# Error 400 when making a DELETE request to delete user account using axios

Tags: next.js, axios

I am trying to implement a functionality to delete a user account in my next.js application. I am using the axios library to make a DELETE request to the server API endpoint. However, I keep getting an error 400 (Bad Request) when I execute the handleDeleteAccount function.

Here's the code for the handleDeleteAccount function:

```
const handleDeleteAccount = () => {
  const data = {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  };

  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  };

  axios
    .delete("http://192.168.0.72:4000/api/auth/deleteAccount", {
      headers,
      data: data,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      router.push("./register");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

I have confirmed that the username, email, password, and token variables contain the correct values. The server API endpoint is reachable, and I can successfully make other requests to it using axios. However, when I try to make the DELETE request with the specified headers and data, it returns a 400 error.

Comment: Hi,
Can you please add your server side code too ?
Also you don't need to add the data you can just extract it from the token on serverside if it's valid.